# ggplot2: override scale_x_datetime with custom month labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a bit of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(farm = c("F1", "F1", 
"F1", "F1"), index = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("HT", "Mid-T", "Outside Mid-T", "Outside South"
), class = "factor"), sensorheight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yrmonth = structure(c(1491004800, 
1496275200, 1491004800, 1496275200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), monthindex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Spring", 
"Winter"), class = "factor"), N = c(2, 2, 1, 1), TempC = c(2.06446759259259, 
6.68402777777778, 1.32268518518518, 5.63194444444445), sd = c(1.17081824208967, 
0.034373246307681, NA, NA), se = c(0.827893518518518, 0.0243055555555567, 
NA, NA), ci = c(10.5193845460483, 0.308831365115372, NA, NA)), .Names = c("farm", 
"index", "sensorheight", "yrmonth", "monthindex", "N", "TempC", 
"sd", "se", "ci"), row.names = c(7L, 9L, 20L, 22L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to graph it with custom month labels on the x-axis:

```
labels <- c('March*', 'April', 'May*', 'June', 'July')
```

When I add the labels it doesn't put the labels in the correct order:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=yrmonth,y=TempC)) +    
   geom_line(size=.4) +    
   geom_point(size=1.5) +      
   scale_x_datetime(name = " ", date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = labels) +   
   scale_y_continuous(name = "Monthly Average Maximum Temperature at 1 m (°C)")
```

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your example code. For instance, what is `lfMonthlyMaxTemp`?

Comment: For a start you may want to put the month names in inverted commas `'March*'`

Comment: Okay should be fixed. Thats what I get for posting to quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define order via factor levels

```
labels <- c("March*", "April", "May*", "June", "July")
labels <- factor(labels,levels=labels)
```

Comment: Its giving the error `Error in format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz), format, usetz, ...) : 
  invalid 'format' argument`

Comment: Does this error appear when you run the example code you provided, or when you run your actual code? Your example code runs fine for me.

Comment: When I run the example code. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Just tried it again, got the error. `ggplot` isn't accepting the format you set for `yrmonth`. I'm not familiar with using `POSIX` so I can't help you there

Comment: It's a type of date format. `ggplot` generally prefers it when plotting time series data.

Comment: Figured it out, it's the difference between `date_labels` and `labels` within `scale_x_datetime`. 

Use `scale_x_datetime(name = " ", date_breaks = "1 month",  labels = labels)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `date_labels = labels` to `POSIXlt` format; for example, to display month and year use `scale_x_datetime(name = " ", date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y")`

This code was modified from the tutorial at [this link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/06/customizing-time-and-date-scales-in-ggplot2/)